# How to run Applets on Android?

Tags: java, android, applet

[KGS app](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_games/brain_puzzle/kgs-client_dxnk.html) seems to run applets, I need to figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android does not support applets and is missing a very large number of classes needed for applets.

Comment: But this application seems to add those classes somehow. And run them.

Comment: @DeBuGGeR: It can't add those classes. The app you have linked to would appear to be a regular Android application.

Comment: http://androidforums.com/sprint-hero-all-things-root/67770-run-webpage-java-applets-w-root-somehow.html here, check this out

Comment: @DeBuGGeR: That app is not using an applet. The forum post you link to does not say that it is using an applet. You cannot run applets on Android.